# download manager class crashes when try to download multiple files?

Tags: android, performance, android-download-manager

i am trying to download images from the web when my app is connected to the internet through this code

```
public void downloadimages(String url,String filename)
        {
          String ur1=url,v1=filename;
          downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
          Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(ur1);
          DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
          request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
          request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
          request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
          request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(),Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,v1 + ".jpg");
          downloadManager.enqueue(request);     

        }
```

when i run the app first time downloads happen but the app crashes after that the app did'nt open i am checking for the dowloaded files also:

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.webdata/files/Download/" + extra2 + ".jpg";
                 tt1.append(path);
                 File f = new File(path);
                  if(f.exists())
                  { 
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File already exists....",
                        //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                  }
                  else
                  {
                   downloadimages(extra,extra2);
                  }
```

if the file has been downloaded previously it should not be dowloaded next time ,but i my app crashes and i don't know why any help guys.........
this is my logcat output:-

```
02-21 18:00:41.547: E/AndroidRuntime(23964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webdata/com.example.webdata.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1088, size is 1088
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us the code `MainActivity` class, because it seems that the error comes from this class.

then the error is a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so have you tried with less image eg 10 or 20? and run later when the first 10 are recovered?